# How to migrate the sonatype-nexus repository from one instance to another?

Tags: migration, maven, nexus

We have two nexus instances running on two different Linux servers.
We are planning to have only single instance for all apps and hence wanted to move the repositories from a smaller nexus to another one.

In [Nexus Tip: Moving Artifacts Between Nexus Repositories](https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/04/nexus-tip-moving-artifacts-between-nexus-repositories/), they said we can just download the repositories from storage path one instance to another but on same machine.

Can someone give some accurate steps here?

Comment: Perhaps [n3dr](https://github.com/030/n3dr) could be useful. More details have been added to the related [Q&A](https://serverfault.com/q/238911/215599).

Answer (score -1):

I'm currently looking into this without finding a satisfying solution to be quite honest. The best so far seems to be migrating blob stores - https://support.sonatype.com/hc/en-us/articles/235816228-Relocating-Blob-Stores.